# Mouse Scroll Events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on some code that detects when you are scrolling the mouse up or down. I want the user to scroll left and right, instead of up and down. My code detects the mouse movements and whether it is up and down. My question is, is there code in jQuery or Javascript that allows the user to scroll left or right based on when an event happens, aka the mouse scrolling up or down?

Comment: Nothing. I have no idea where to go. I have a variable that holds either a positive integer (meaning mouse scroll is up) or a negative integer (meaning mouse scroll is down). A tutorial would help, anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/) + [jQuery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo).

```
.mousewheel(function(e, d, dx, dy) {
  $(this).scrollTo((dy<0?'+':'-')+'='+10*Math.abs(dy)+'px', 0, {axis: 'x'});
  e.preventDefault();
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PyCkq/1/).

Comment: Hmmm... the demo is not working on Firefox but only on Chrome.

Comment: @jason328 Works for me in Firefox 14 on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Tie a function to your user mouse up movement and use jQuery's scrollTo plugin.  Here's a tutorial detailing it: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Hope this helps!